# Newbie Haskell lyah tutorial on list types

Tags: haskell

This is from chapter 3 in the famous Learn You a Haskell book. My question and confusion is explained in this code:

```
-- simple lyah tutorial function. by itself this makes sense.
head' :: [a] -> a
head' [] = error "'head' on empty list"
head' (x:_) = x

-- It is my understanding that [3] is the same as 3:[]. Why do they don't work the same?
head' [3]   -- works. returns 3.
head' 3:[] -- doesn't work. I can not understand error.
head' (3:[]) -- works. returns 3.

-- Now in GHCi, I can look at the types.
-- Why do some use the variable name t and the others use a?
-- Beyond the t/a discrepancy, the types are identical. why?
*Main> :t [3]
[3] :: Num t => [t]
*Main> :t (3:[])
(3:[]) :: Num a => [a]
*Main> :t 3:[]
3:[] :: Num a => [a]
```

Answer (score 8):

Function application has a higher priority than any infix operator in Haskell. Therefore, if you write

```
head' 3:[]
```

it parses as

```
(head' 3) : []
```

rather than

```
head' (3 : [])
```

The application of `head'` to `3` isn't type correct, because there's usually no `Num` instance for lists, and therefore you'll get a type error.

Comment: thanks. I should have guessed that. i will accept this answer as soon as the timer allows.